# C++ Slow execution time of template complex image reading class, with separated declaration and implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, stl, execution-time

I'm trying to make binary files of complex images reading. I use VisualStudio 2010. HERE is the **code1**:

```c++
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <conio.h>
      #include <iostream>
      #include <fstream>
      #include <math.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #define NX 21843
      #define NY 22380
      #include <windows.h>

    class CTimer
    {
    public:
        CTimer() 
        {
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&mqFreq);
        }
        ~CTimer() {}

        void Start() 
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&mqStart);
        }
        void End() 
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&mqEnd);
        }
        double GetTimeInSeconds()
        {
            return (mqEnd.QuadPart - mqStart.QuadPart)/static_cast<double>(mqFreq.QuadPart);
        }
    private:
        LARGE_INTEGER mqStart;
        LARGE_INTEGER mqEnd;
        LARGE_INTEGER mqFreq;
    };

    using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    CTimer Time;
    Time.Start();
    ifstream INFILE;
    INFILE.open("e:\\WORK\\CIMG.bindat", ios::binary);

    short ***im_ptr;
    im_ptr = new short** [2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        im_ptr[i] = new short* [NX];
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            im_ptr[i][j] = new short [NY];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<NY; k++){
                int index = i*NY*NX + j*NY + k;
                INFILE.read((char*)&im_ptr[i][j][k], sizeof(short));
                if (index == 2*NX*NY-1){
                    INFILE.close();}
            }
        }
    } 

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            delete[] im_ptr[i][j];
        }
        delete[] im_ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] im_ptr;

    Time.End();
    std::cout << Time.GetTimeInSeconds() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nPress any key to exit" << std::endl;
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

This code work fine, but only with SHORT-type images.

I decided to do template-class, that allows read images of many different data types, and that separates declaration and implementation. HERE is the **code2**:

of stdafx.h - with declaration of my class

```c++
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

template<typename DataType> 
class SARDataLoader
{
private:
    int day,month,year; 
public:
    DataType*** LoadComplexImage(int, int);
    int DeleteImageFromMemory(DataType***, int);
};
```

of SARDataLoader_C.cpp - with implementation of my class

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename DataType> 
DataType*** SARDataLoader<DataType>::LoadComplexImage(int NX, int NY){
    using namespace std;
    ifstream INFILE;
    INFILE.open(""e:\\WORK\\CIMG.bindat"", ios::binary);
    DataType ***im_ptr;
    im_ptr = new DataType** [2];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        im_ptr[i] = new DataType* [NX];
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            im_ptr[i][j] = new DataType [NY];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<NY; k++){
                int index = i*NY*NX + j*NY + k;
                INFILE.read((char*)&im_ptr[i][j][k], sizeof(DataType));
                if (index == 2*NX*NY-1){
                    INFILE.close();}
            }
        }
    }
    return im_ptr;
};

template<typename DataType> int SARDataLoader<DataType>::DeleteImageFromMemory(DataType*** im_ptr, int NX){
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<NX; j++){
            delete[] im_ptr[i][j];
        }
        delete[] im_ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] im_ptr;
    return 112345;
};

template class SARDataLoader<short>;//explicit instantiation short
```

of MAIN.cpp - using my class

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#define NX 21843
#define NY 22380
#include <windows.h>

class CTimer
{
public:
    CTimer() 
    {
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&mqFreq);
    }
    ~CTimer() {}

    void Start() 
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&mqStart);
    }
    void End() 
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&mqEnd);
    }
    double GetTimeInSeconds()
    {
        return (mqEnd.QuadPart - mqStart.QuadPart)/static_cast<double>(mqFreq.QuadPart);
    }
private:
    LARGE_INTEGER mqStart;
    LARGE_INTEGER mqEnd;
    LARGE_INTEGER mqFreq;
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    CTimer Time;
    Time.Start();
    std::cout <<"\nIMAGE1 Loading..."<< std::endl;

    SARDataLoader<short> IMG_LOADER;
    short ***im_ptr = IMG_LOADER.LoadComplexImage(NX, NY);

    int CODE = IMG_LOADER.DeleteImageFromMemory(im_ptr, NX);

    Time.End();
    double run_time = Time.GetTimeInSeconds();
    std::cout <<CODE<<"\nRUNTIME "<<run_time<<" seconds"<<"\n...Press any key to exit...\n"<<std::endl;
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

This code work, and does the same thing as **code1**.
I use CTimer-class for **code1** and **code2** execution time measuring.
And it say that **code2** execution time is almost three times slower than **code1**.
Can anyone tell me what causes it and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually in computer science we don't use the term **runtime** to describe *the time for a program to finish execution*

Comment: Maybe by splitting up allocation `new` and deallocation `delete` in two separate functions, it is harder for the compiler to optimize the whole thing. I think you could just use a single allocation and deallocation, and similarly a single loop to read the image. The compiler might optimize the first code to do that, but it might be much harder for the second code, as there are data members and separate functions to consider.

Comment: Of course the first question should be *"Did you compile with optimizations enabled / in Release mode?"* ;)

Comment: Just curious, if speed were your concern, and since NX and NY are fixed, is there some special reason you don't just use: `short (*nvals)[NX][NY] = new short[2][NX][NY];` to grab all the memory in a single shot, and then bulk read the entire thing in one hit to the IO system?

Comment: Yes, @DyP in *release mode* **code1** and **code2** have almost the same execution time:) But i want decrease execution time in *debug* mode.

Comment: @WhozCraig, in this example NX and NY are fixed. But in my full program code NX and NY are not fixed.

Comment: Then only compile this one TU with optimizations on, and everything else with optimizations off ;)

Comment: @paulm I'm doing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the assembly code produced by the two examples (non-optimized compiles) there are only two  differences that I noticed:

1. dealing with the `NX` and `NY` values required actual calculations in the templated version because they're passed as parameters while the original code they were hard-coded constants (via `#define`s). However the amount of work that was added to the templated code looked to be insignificant - I can't imagine they resulted in a measurable difference in execution time.
2. the templated code calls the destructor for the `ifstream INFILE` when it returns from `LoadComplexImage()` - the execution time for this is included in the timer in the templated version.  Since the dtor for `INFILE` isn't called until `main()` returns in the original code it isn't including in the timing for that example.

I can believe that the dtor for an `ifstream` can take a measurable amount of time (and the one in the debug library might be quite slow).  Since I have no idea what the timings are for these runs, I don't know whether it would account for a 200% increase. But it seems to me to be the likely culprit for at least a large chunk of the increase, if not all of it.

To compare apples-to-apples, you'll need to rejigger the original test to include the destruction of the `INFILE`, or move the opening of the input file outside of the timed code in both cases, and pass it into the templated version as a reference (or use a global for test purposes).  Keeping the open & close of the input file outside of the timed area seems like the better choice for benchmarking this stuff.